# Why history.push(<router name>) not navigating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history, react-router-dom

I'm building a login page. Where I want to redirect the user if the login successfully otherwise it should redirect to the login page.

Note: Without the use of redux.

I tried to create a router history by "react-router-dom" and when I push a new endpoint in the search bar the router gets updated but it doesn't change the screen. I also tried to change the screen by "window.location.reload()" but then the problem is how I'll send the user data to the next screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from "./components/Login"
import signUp from "./components/signUp"
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard"
import Recordings from "./components/Recordings"
import RauteHistory from './components/routeHistory';
import callDetails from './components/callDetails'
const routing = (
  <Router history={RauteHistory}>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={signUp} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/recordings" component={Recordings} />
            <Route path="/calldetails" component={callDetails} />
    </div>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

```
const loginButtonClick = () => {
    let userId, password
    userId = document.getElementById("userId").value;
    password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  loginService(userId, password)
        .then(responseJson => {
            if (responseJson.user_id){
                RauteHistory.push('/dashboard')
                window.location.reload()
            }
            else {
                handleClick()
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.error);
        });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is inside `RouteHistory` component. But try to wrap your routes inside `<Switch>` from `react-router-dom`. And use `props.history.push('/dashboard')`

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ? I think the error is blocking you from navigating to other page.

Comment: I hope you are using react-router v4.
Have a look on this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

Comment: @ Ashish, I tried to use <Switch> but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Suniltc, No There is no error in the console.